# how to style the sides of an html element?

Tags: html, css

I have a part of this site where I want H3s that look like this...

------------------- Centered Text Here -------------------

where the "---" parts are fancy wiggley background images. The left one and the right one are reflections of each other.

So one option is...

```
<h3>
    <div class="left-image-thing"></div>
    <span>Centered Text Here</span>
    <div class="right-image-thing"></div>
</h3>
```

...and put the images in the divs around the span. But I'd like to just have...

```
<h3>Centered Text Here</h3>
```

...and just use css for the left and right background images. Is there a way to do this? just one tag, css, etc?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [pseudo elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Pseudo-elements), `:before` and `:after`:

```
h3 {
   text-align: center;
}

h3:before { 
    content: url('myimageurl1.png');
}

h3:after { 
    content: url('myimageurl2.png');
}
```

Of course your CSS will be more complex, but this is a way to handle your use case.

**EDIT**: here's [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/edelman/gYX25/).

Comment: when i do that I get.......... image.pngCentered Text Hereimage.png
........instead of........
[actual image]Centered Text Here[actual image]
........so, is there a way to tell the "content" css attribute that the data is "safe" to render as html?

Answer (score 0):

Psuedo elements scare me because we need to support lower end browsers... this will work everywhere (even low end):

CSS:

```
h3 {
   background: url('myimageurl1.png') no-repeat left middle;
   padding-left: 100px /*This should be the width of myimageurl1.png */
}

h3 span {
   background: url('myimageurl2.png') no-repeat right middle;
   padding-right: 100px /*This should be the width of myimageurl2.png */
}
```

HTML:

```
<h3><span>Centered Text Here</span></h3>
```